# Exposing various ports behind a load balancer on Rancher/AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, rancher, aws-elb

I am setting up a Rancher environment.

The Rancher server is behind a classic ELB (since ALBs are not recommended per Rancher [guidelines](http://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/installing-rancher/installing-server/#running-rancher-server-behind-an-application-load-balancer-alb-in-aws)).

I also want to make available Prometheus and Grafana services.

These are offered via Rancher catalogue and will run as container services, being exposed on Rancher host ports 3000 and 9090.

Since Rancher server (per their recommendations) *requires* ELB, I wanted to explore the options on how to make available the two services above using the most minimal possible setup.

If the server is available on say `rancher.mydomain.com`, ideally I would like to have the other two on `grafana.mydomain.com` and `prometheus.mydomain.com`.

Can I at least combine the later two behind an ALB?

If so, how do I map them?

Do I place `<my_rancher_host_public_IP>:3000` and `<my_rancher_host_public_IP>:9090` behind an ALB?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this a couple (maybe more) ways:

- use an external dns updater like the route 53 infra catalog item. That will automatically map dns directly to the public ip of the host that houses the services. Modify the dns template so it prepends the service name to the domain.
- register your targets  and map the ports, then set a dns entry to the ALB.

The first way will allow for dns to update in case the service shifts across hosts in your environment. You could leverage the second way and force containers to specific hosts.